# Unable to remove "null" text using inspector tool

Tags: html, css, web-inspector

I think we can delete every element of a website from the inspector tool on chrome.

But here's the issue. I was using google calendar on chrome, and what i did was i added `style="filter: invert(100%)"` to the html container.

(I know it is silly to invert a website like that, but i was just testing some of my css)

After i did this, everything was inverted on the website, however a text "null" appeared on the top of the website:

[image: picture]

Then, i searched for the null element, and tried to delete it, but the delete option itself is not there. I'm very confused, i have tried searching this on google and stack overflow itself, but no one seems to have the same problem as me :/

Can anyone offer some guidance?

Comment: That is very strange-- unfortunately, I am not able to recreate it...

Comment: Did you try the delete button?

Comment: @YevheniiShlapak i tried right clicking it but there seems to be no option for deleting, like on the picture. It is very confusing :/

Answer (score 0):

I can delete it.
I think it has to do with the fact that Google continues to send the full status of the page as xhr internally at regular time intervals and receive responses for security and other reasons. As a result of this request, null is returned as a response and displayed on the screen.
[image: I can delete it.]

Comment: Ohh, so is there a way for me to delete it?

Comment: what you mean, manual delete or programatic delete? As shown in the figure, you can manually delete as many times as you want.

Comment: i mean manually delete. Why does your delete button appear but not mines?